# After signing a contract, will they give me time to settle things at my current job?

Tags: professionalism, hiring-process, ethics

I've been through a long interview process, almost two months now, for a job in a huge multinational company.

Last week they contacted me to schedule the psycho-technic evaluation; and it seems I'm in the final stage of the race.

But now, I'm a bit concerned because I was thinking about what will happen if they hire me.

Is there a chance that they will tell me, "Right, you start right away", or will they give me a few weeks to settle things at my current job?

The process has been long, but I never had any kind of confirmation through it; I could have been removed from the process at any moment, so I didn't feel the need to say anything at my current job.

Now I’m waiting for what I hope will be the final call. What do you guys think, or know about how multinational companies handle the hiring process?

Should I say something at my work? I really do not want to talk about it unless it is 100% confirmed, but are there any chances that they will want me to start working right away?

Comment: Two months interview process?!?!! Are they serious!?

Comment: The contract you sign will include a start date, which you can agree to (i.e. sign) or negotiate, much like any other part of the contract.

Comment: What does your current contract say? I live in the UK and having just accepted a new job I handed in my notice and am contractually obliged to work for another four weeks at my existing job before I can start my new one.

Comment: 2 months to decide to hire someone is expensive for them (worth it perhaps to avoid paying the wrong person for many years). Next to the cost of doing the hiring processes, any cost associated with not having you start for a few weeks is likely negligable -- so I would expect them to be flexible.

Comment: You may also want to consider whether or not you are able to quit on the spot if you do get the job.  Some companies have options built into the employment contract that prevent an employee from leaving abruptly, and require them to stay `x` number of days past the point of notice.  This can usually be waived, but I've seen many cases where it is not, and some employees are retained for up to three months after they give notice.

Comment: The question asks strangers on the internet to predict the future behavior of people you know and we do not. If you want to know how people you know and we do not will behave in the future, you could ask them; we cannot.

Comment: @JackTwain It took me ~3 months to get hired at a State Position as a Contractor in the US. It'll take a ~year to get hired on directly (more or less). 2 months might be outside of normal, but not extreme. I took the job due to the benefits, the atmosphere and it was well worth the wait. Once I got the job, they were more than willing to wait the additional 2 week notice I put in at my previous job. After all... you're in for 2 months, why not 3? And giving notice at previous job... tells them that you'll give them the same consideration in the future (if/when it comes to that).

Comment: Have they honestly not asked at any point in this two month interview process what your notice period is at your current job??

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> Is there a chance that they will tell me, "Right, you start right
>   away", or will they give me a few weeks to settle things in my current
>   job?

Anything is possible, but in almost every locale, there will be a formal (and perhaps legally-mandated) or informal notice period.

In the US, in my field at least, it's customary to give at least two weeks notice before leaving. Virtually any employer would respect that notice period, and give you at least two weeks to settle things.

Wait until you get a formal offer. Then negotiate the details - including your starting date. Before negotiating, think through how much notice time you would prefer.

Answer (score 9):

It rather depends on which country you're in.  For example, I've got a 3 month notice period - which is fairly standard in the UK.

Have they never asked you what your notice period is?

If they want to hire you, they have no reason to complain about whatever the normal notice period is in your country.

What normally happen is, if they want you, they'll send you a contract and you'll negotiate your pay, benefit, and start date.  Once you've reached mutually agreeable figures (for example, they'll pay you extra if you quit before your current job's bonus is paid) that's when you hand in your resignation.

Comment: 3 months isn't standard for the UK. It's usually 1 month, but then growing with years of employment. I think the statutory notice period is 1 month, then after a year, it goes up by 1 week every year of employment up to a maximum of 3 months.

Comment: @DanHanly You're confusing the notice given by the employer and the employee. In law, an employer must give one week's notice, plus one week for each complete year worked after the first, up to a maximum of 12 weeks total. An employee needs to give at least one week's notice by law, but an employment contract may increase that amount; I'm not sure if there's a maximum. (Source: [ACAS](http://www.acas.org.uk/index.aspx?articleid=4096).)

Comment: Sorry, I should have said "fairly standard for large tech companies in the UK."

Answer (score 4):

**Simply ask** the new company. There should be plenty of opportunity when the interview process takes so long. What answer comes will tell you something about the company besides the actual information you need. Remember - interview process is a two way thing.

In my field (software engineering) in the European countries I happend to take a look into hiring processes it is fairly common to simply ask the candidate from which date he'd like to start. Unless you are in a specific or high turnaround field, companies are usually fairly flexible in terms of weeks or event a month back and forth. I personally signed my contract about eight months prior to my first day on the job, the date being agreed upon prior to signing the contract.

Answer (score 4):

One thing to remember is that companies generally like to think that their employees will be responsible. If you turn around to a company and say for example *"I'd love to start immediately as I'm really keen to begin here, but I'm right in the middle of a project at my current company and could use 6 weeks to finish that so I don't leave them in the lurch"*.

Then you are showing that you like to finish things, that you take pride in the results of your work, and that hopefully they can expect you not to abandon them if or when the time comes for you to move on once more.

Those are all positive attributes of an employee, not negative ones.